# Forecasting multiple data sets - mean and standard deviation

Tags: probability, statistics

I have multiple data sets A through F that represent a time to complete a task using different methods.  From these I have calculated mean, standard deviation, etc.

Using mean and standard deviation I'd like to calculate the probability that A is faster than B, C, D, etc.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that it is possible to calculate probability of two randomly-picked variables. It is the same as saying:

What is the probability that x is greater than y?

I believe that you can only have probability if you have a domain or set. I may be wrong, but you have a very good question! Thanks!